# Is there a way to access multiple Eclipse packages from one version of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to use multiple different Eclipse packages (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers, and Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers). Is there a way to install them all but be able to access them all from a single version of Eclipse.exe?

I have installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers separately as .exes but when I run Eclipse IDE for Java Developers I don't see the options to create a Web project like when I ran Eclipse IDE for Java and Web Developers. Is there a way to be able to access all packages from a single version of Eclipse.exe or do I have to run each version of Eclipse separately when I want to do coding with a specific language? I'd greatly appreciate anyone's help

Comment: The only thing you can do is to check the Marketplace within eclipse. If you navigate to `Help>Eclipse Marketplace`, you'll be able to install plugins. I don't know if you can use C/C++ then, but that's the only option I am aware of. Alternatively, check the website: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/. There are some tools that might suit your needs. For example this: `Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.30.` If this is not what you want.. Then I don't think it's possible. Note: I'm not an eclipse expert :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, combining support for multiple languages into a single installation is both one of Eclipse's biggest strengths and weaknesses. The Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers already is a superset of what's in the Java IDE download, and you can still add more to it. It's possible to add so much to it that your IDE becomes too heavy, with plug-ins potentially interfering with each other because the ecosystem is just that big by now.

For generic instructions, you can visit the Help reference at https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-124.htm .

Because I'm less familiar with the C++ download, I'd suggest starting with that and adding the Web Tools (which will pull in the Java Tools as well) via the instructions at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F or using https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-enterprise-java-and-web-developer-tools. You'll see the Maven and Gradle support as options during this process, as well as the server adapters that are offered from WTP.